# Can I visit japan again this year after I’ve visited 105 days but was given 2 90 day visit passport

Tags: repeat-visits, japanese-visitors

Can I go to japan after I was given 2 90 day stickers in my passport but only stayed 104 days total? One visit 90 days and the second 2 weeks. I did not have my return flight at the time of my entry the second time so they gave me 90 days but I returned home after two weeks so no way to tell passport wise when I returned home as in no arrival sticker from my homeland. But I want to come back for 2 months this year. Is that possible

Comment: What is your citizenship? It sounds like you entered as a visa-exempt tourist both times? In which case AFAIK the second entry permission ended when you left Japan and isn’t valid for a subsequent entry.

Comment: Just a Tourist both times.

Comment: I didn’t stay the whole 90days and told them I’d be staying only 2 weeks

Comment: I didn’t have my return flight at the time I was leaving the country I was at to go to japan. That’s when they gave me the 90day sticker but I booked it before the flight so at Japan immagration they wouldn’t ask further questions. But never got the sticker changed to only 2 weeks.

Comment: If you’re a citizen of a visa-exempt country the period of stay granted at the time of the landing permission will normally be "90 days". https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html Spending 104 days and then returning for another two months probably isn’t the typical ‘tourist’ profile

Comment: A 90-day visa doesn't mean you have to stay that long. It's the maximum time you can stay. Japanese immigration will routinely give these to everyone coming from certain countries unless they feel there's some risk.